# They are somebody who ... (plural indefinite pronouns)

Tags: pronouns, singular-vs-plural

Can we say "they are somebody who deserve it"? Meaning they are the kind of people who deserve it. If so, should we use third person version and write "deserves"?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody is singular. They (i.e. one person, non-gender, he or she) are somebody/someone who deserves it. They (plural) are people who deserve it.

Deserves is third person singular; deserve is third person plural.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you're using *they* as a plural pronoun or as a singular gender-neutral pronoun—something which has recently become a stylistic choice.

Depending on your use of *they*, there are a few grammatically correct options:

> They are (the kind of) **people** who **deserve** it.

This is used when you are talking about more than one person.

> They are (the kind of) **person** who **deserves** it.
>   They are **somebody** who **deserves** it.

This is used when you are talking about a single person of indeterminate gender.

The second examples sound correct to me (as I've become used to using *they* in a singular sense), however they may not sound correct to everybody. The other stylistic options include *he or she is* or a rephrasing.

Comment: I am reminded of the education reporter who told us that **the child had done their homework by themselves**. It may be (politically) correct but it's painful!

Comment: @RonaldSole The latest "grammar" would be **the child had done their homework by** ***themself.*** ;)

Comment: I'd have said: *The child had done its homework by itself* but this is no longer acceptable, I think because English has lost the distinction between the gender of the word and the sex of the referent. In Portuguese the word *ovary* is masculine, never mind that the organ belongs in women. And there are numerous other examples in Latin languages.